# Android Button Reference?

Tags: android

So I'm having some issues with a method I'm going to be using to change a button's color based on a number received from the game engine (so if it returned 0 it would be red, 1 would change it to blue, 2 would change it to yellow) but I keep getting errors when trying to reference the button.

I'm referencing the buttons in this way:

```
Button x0y0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x0y0);
```

But I am getting an error, eclipse does not recognize

Any help on how I can get buttons into this program and have them change color based on what the engine returns to it?

Comment: the method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ButtonColorUpdate(my class this method is in)

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't a runtime error but a compile error?

Comment: Gonna need to see your code. From what I can tell, you tried to use findViewById from a class that doesn't support it. Post your code

Comment: you need to call this in your Activity or have reference to Activity in ButtonColorUpdate class and call it reference.findViewById(...)

Comment: LOL!  'I'm getting an error'.  Yeah, I hate errors too.  But I think there might be a reason that when errors occur they do more than just say "Error.", don't you?  Can't you imagine that possibly, just sometimes, the error might be useful in determining what the problem is, and how to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `ButtonColorUpdate` will have to extend `Activity` to get access to `findViewById()`.  It seems more likely, however, that you will want to pass the actual button to your `ButtonColorUpdate` class since it sounds like a helper class rather than a UI class.

You could also pass your activity to the `ButtonColorUpdate` class's constructor and then use that to get the ID of the button.

Answer (score 0):

findViewById() is a public method of either the Activity or the View class. So you can only call it on/in those objects.